# Multiple attributes nested in one attribute for MsTest

Tags: c#, mstest, custom-attributes

I have the following test in C# and I use MsTest:

```
using TestMethod=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute;
using TestClass=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute;
using Owner=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.OwnerAttribute;
using Description=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DescriptionAttribute;
using Timeout=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TimeoutAttribute;

namespace DataGroup
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Data
    {
    [Owner("Tester")]
    [TestMethod, Timeout(5000)]
    [Description(@"This is a sample test")]
    public void TestCase_001()
    {

    }
    }
}
```

In the above code, in the line,

> [TestMethod, Timeout(5000)]

Instead of this line, can we add a custom attribute and refer 'TestMethod' and 'Timeout' attribute?

If possible, Will it be impact on my test framework? MsTest can still identify my tests and able to execute the tests without any impact?

Comment: what do you mean by refer TestMethod and Timout?  Could you show what you WANT to do in addition to what you have above?

Comment: you can do that just fine!

Comment: @DanielA.White, Can you please explain in brief how can I do that?

Comment: `[TestMethod][Timeout(5000)]`

Comment: @DanielA.White, Oh 'separate' word created confusion. I edited it as 'custom' attribute now. My problem is, In 200 test case I should include these two attributes. Instead like #define in C, I want to add only one attribute which framework refers testmethod and timeout attributes.

Comment: For eg, if it was in C, I would have defined it like this `#define TestMethod TestMethod,Timeout(5000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# does not support multiple inheritance, so you cannot create an attribute that inherits from both `TestMethodAttribute` and `TimeoutAttribute`.

You'll have to live with having both attributes on every method.

Note, if all tests need the same timeout value, you can use the [TestSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243175.aspx#timeoutalltests) file to specify the global timeout value.

Comment: As I am using ordered test, if I give any timeout value in TestSettings file, I will abort the rest of the tests and it will go in 'Not Executed' state. So I have to define timeout value for each test case. :(